# Question: How to find equation for any graph using R?

Tags: regression

I need to find a equation which can be used to describe this data. I'm not sure on how to obtain the equation using R and other (i am beginner in this). First I plotted a graph and found my input data is not linear so i checked for non-linear model.I performed Power and polynomial function and got very similar R-square values. I am not sure how to interpret the results and get the best fit model (equation) to this data. Can anyone please help in this. My input data is given below:

genomes(x) genes(y)

1. 153621 26752
2. 151621 26986
3. 159621 26065
4. 101621 35259
5. 21621 78756
6. 155621 26503
7. 121621 31358
8. 141621 28308
9. 81621 40520
10. 157621 26282
11. 160621 25963
12. 61621 47846
13. 161621 25868

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, **Welcome the the site !** and **Happy New Year !**.

Looking at a scatter plot of the data, it seems that an hyperbolic function could be suitable, that is to say
$$y=\frac {a+bx}{1+cx}$$ Using a nonlinear regression, this would give $a=125090$, $b=0.134069$ and $c=2.89219\times 10^{-5}$ and $R^2=0.999999$; all parameters are statistically significant.

Rounded to the next integer, the predicted values are

$$\{26766,27003,26082,35215,78747,26533,31299,28273,40478,26305,25972,47930,25863\}$$ which seems to be almost perfect.

Comment: What software did you use to find the form of the equation other than "looking at the data plot" .?

Comment: @IrishStat. I just "looked" at the data (and I am almost blind).